# Page redirect function

Tags: community, redirect, web

Looking to infleunce a direct page route after one submits Donation or Event form within Linvio. We wish to redirect to a page not housed within Salesforce. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please add more detail and relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Jessica. Typically questions need to be quite tight and focused, have you tried to do this? If so, where have you gotten stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PageReference class to redirect the user to different, even to a url which is outside of Salesforce. Here is an example.

```
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;
```